# Is this a GCC bug? Initializing structs with unions

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, unions, compiler-bug

I may have found a bug with GCC v4.8.2, but I want to check first before I submit it as it could be me doing something wrong!

The following code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
struct Message
{
  typedef union {
    char byte;
    const char *str;
  } Parameter;

  Parameter p1;
  Parameter p2;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Message> messages_;

  messages_.push_back({{ .byte = 'a' }});

  Message message = {{ .byte = 'a' }, { .str = "Hello World" }};
  messages_.push_back(message);

  messages_.push_back({{ .byte = 'a' }, { .str = "Hello World" }});
}
```

`clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp` compiles this fine. However `g++` outputs this:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:23:66: internal compiler error: in reshape_init_class, at cp/decl.c:5216
   messages_.push_back({{ .byte = 'a' }, { .str = "Hello World" }});
                                                                  ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/ccrf5vwr.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.
```

I'll submit this as a bug if nobody has any ideas, although in my experience a programmers problem is almost never a compiler bug and almost always a fault of his own!

Comment: `Please submit a full bug report` is already the answer

Comment: Internal compiler error is always a compiler bug.

Comment: Technically, I'd say this should require `-std=g++11` to compile, as designated initialisers (or whatever they're called) are C, not C++.

Comment: @Angew GCC's `-std=c++11` is only intended to let valid C++11 code compile. Some extensions that are not in conflict with the standard are still enabled without any warning, you need `-pedantic` or even `-pedantic-errors` to have GCC point them out. (And even then, not all extensions are disabled.)

Comment: If you do something wrong, the compiler should report a normal compilation error. An internal error is a crash, and always a bug (hence the notice at the bottom). Please proceed with the reporting :)

Comment: I think this is the same bug as [one that has already been reported](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR59832), and if so, no need to re-report it.

Comment: I've added it as a comment to that one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered in the comments above: Any error message you get from GCC that includes the phrases `internal compiler error` and `Please submit a full bug report` is definitely a compiler bug, not your own fault! In this case, the bug appears to be something to do with GCC's parsing of `{{ ... }}` in C++ mode where the "`...`" includes a designated initializer. @Sam has reported it as GCC [bug 59832](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59832).

However, as @Angew pointed out, this line —

```
messages_.push_back({{ .byte = 'a' }});
```

— is **not valid C++.** Standard C++ doesn't allow designated initializers; that's a C99 feature that was not adopted into C++ (neither C++11 nor C++14).

As for *why* designated initializers have been problematic to add to C++, see [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.std.c++/i3MxsIeQRa0/3AgEqLdsnH8J), where Doug Gregor asks how the compiler should interpret things like

```
struct Foo {int x,y; };
void f(Foo);
void f(std::initializer_list<int>);

int main(){
    f({1});
    f({1,2});
    f({1,2,3});
    f({.x=1});
    f({.x=1,2});
    f({.x=1,2,3});
}
```

For the record, GCC 4.8 treats all six as calls to `f(initializer_list<int>)`. Clang 3.5 treats the first three as calls to `f(initializer_list<int>)`, the next two as calls to `f(Foo)`, and the last one as ill-formed. Basically, it's a non-standard construct: different compilers are within their rights to treat it differently, *and they do*.

Comment: FWIW, clang's behaviour is exactly what I would have expected.